# Insert Excel validation list in excel using Javascript

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, office-addins, office-app, officedev

We are using Excel 2016 Add-In to load data from DB to **Excel 2016** (few Excel 2013). There is a column 'Status' in Excel. **Currently it is simple text cell. We need Excel drop-down list** in Status cell (refer below example image).
We are using JavaScript for loading Excel '*Office.context.document*'. We need the solution in JavaScript.
Please provide **a solution in JavaScript**, C# or Insert HTML in Excel etc.
Thanks in Advance...
[image]

Comment: Is there a code that shows what you have tried so far? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: We worked on below:
1) We tried to create array and insert into cell using 'Tables and matrices'. Refer below link for 'Tables and matrices': 'https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/08/28/writing-data-from-apps-to-office-documents/'
2) We tried to create drop down in HTML and create Excel from HTML.
3) We are working to create JSON and insert into Excel. But did not get any success.

Comment: FYIP... We did not found the solution. Allowed user to enter free text.